# Moving Android app to SD card results in an error

Tags: android

I've started a clean project for testing purpose. All I try to do is enabling the option to move the app to the SD card. I've added the `android:installLocation="auto` to the manifest which now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test.mysdcardpls"
android:installLocation="auto">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After deploying the app to my device I can see that the "move to SD card" option is enabled. However, when I click the button it returns an error message saying that I don't have enough storage (while testing with a clean 16gb SD card). This happens on any device I test this with (Sony xperia z1, Huawei p8 lite, Samsung galaxy s9)

I've also tried using "preferExternal" but this had the same result.
I can't seem to find any information about this issue. Anyone experiencing the same issue?

---

## Solved

Found out that the problem was caused by deploying via Android Studio. When installing the generated APK on the devices it works as a charm.

Comment: You could answer your own question with the solution because in my opinion this question is useful.